# Type contraint problem of C#

Tags: c#, reflection, generics, constraints

I meet a problem about type contraint of c# now.

I wrote a pair of methods that can convert object to string and convert string to object.
ex.

```
static string ConvertToString(Type type, object val) {
 if (type == typeof(string)) return (string)val;
 if (type == typeof(int)) return val.ToString();
 if (type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(CodeObject))) return ((CodeObject)val).Code;
}

static T ConvertToObject<T>(string val) {
 Type type = typeof(T);
 if (type == typeof(string)) return (T)(object)val;
 if (type == typeof(int)) return (T)(object)int.Parse(val);
 if (type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(CodeObject))) return Codes.Get<T>(val);
}
```

where CodeObject is a base class of Employees, Offices ...,
which can fetch by static method Codes.Get where T: CodeObject

but the code above cannot be compiled because error #CS0314

the generic type T of method ConvertToObject have no any constraint
but Codes.Get request T must be subclass of CodeObject

i tried use overloading to solve the problem but not ok.

is there any way to clear up the problem? like reflection?

Comment: please clarify, ConvertToObject<T>(string str) should be ConvertToObject<T>(string val) as str is not referenced in the body of the method but val is.

Comment: 1. `InSubclassOf` --> `IsSubclassOf` 2. `val` --> `str` 3. missing return statements on both methods. It is best to post code that compiles, it helps a lot to get the right answer.

Comment: Given the answers with a type constraint, the type-checks in ConvertToObject are superfluous now, since the generic constraint prevents a user from invoking `ConvertToObject<int>` in the first place. The type-check for `type.InSubclassOf(typeof(CodeObject)` is superfluous, since the constraint guarantees condition always holds. The whole method can be reduced to `T ConvertToObject(string str) { return Codes.Get<T>(str); }`, or just a useless wrapper around another method. In other words, you don't need either method you're trying to write.

Comment: @Juliet You should have answered :)  I've seen you give a lot of comments that are really answers on various questions lately.  Very keen observation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i tried to clear up the problem by reflection.

```
if (type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(CodeObject))) {
    var baseMethod = typeof(Codes).GetMethod("Fetch<>", BindingFlags.Static | BidingFlags.Public, null, new Type[] {typeof(string)}, null);
    if (baseMethod != null) {
        var genericMethod = baseMethod.MakeGenericMethod(type);
        if (genericMethod != null)
            return (T)genericMethod.Invoke(null, new string[] { val });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your function signature needs a type constraint; but since all permutations don't need that constraint I'd make a helper function; something like:

```
static T ConvertToObject<T>(string str) {
 Type type = typeof(T);
 if (type == typeof(string)) return (T)(object)val;
 if (type == typeof(int)) return (T)(object)int.Parse(val);
 if (type.InSubclassOf(typeof(CodeObject))) return ConvertCodeObjectToObject((CodeObject)val);
}

static T ConvertCodeObjectToObject<T>(string str) where T: CodeObject {
 return Codes.Get<T>(val);
}
```

I *think* you have to cast the param to ConvertCodeObjectToObject, because of the Type constraint.

Comment: If you perform the cast, The type for T will always be CodeObject.  Depending on the implementation of Codes.Get<T> this could make a significant difference.

Comment: I should be clear... <T> will always be of type CodeObject and never any of its subclasses.

Comment: Thank you! however, since method defined as ConvertCodeObjectToObject<T>(string),
i have to return ConvertCodeObjectToObject''''<T>''''((CodeObject)val). and the same #CS0314 problem occured.

Answer (score 0):

You want to add a type constraint, like so:

```
static T ConvertToObject<T>(string str) where T : CodeObject
{
    Type type = typeof(T);
    if (type == typeof(string)) return (T)(object)val;
    if (type == typeof(int)) return (T)(object)int.Parse(val);
    if (type.InSubclassOf(typeof(CodeObject))) return Codes.Get<T>(val);
}
```

The type constraint is there "`where T`" bit. You're basically telling the compiler that `T` must be a subclass of `CodeObject`.

Comment: Seems good, but then it cannot return `int` or `object`. The casting method is probably the right answer here.

Comment: If T is constrained to CodeObject, then T cannot be int or string.

Comment: Oh yeah, I missed that part. I think John Weldon's answer is the best in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Your conversion method must have identical constraints to be able to call the `Codes.Get<T>` and satisfy your constraints for `<T>`.

Try this:

```
static T ConvertToObject<T>(string str) where T:CodeObject
{
   return Codes.Get<T>(str);
}
```

Edit: As someone pointed out, now that you have the constraint,  will never be int, or string.  In addition, the check to make sure it is of type CodeObject is done by the constraint.

This essentially makes the wrapping method "extra" and not needed.  Simply call Codes.Get unless you have a good reason for abstracting it.

Hope this helps.